# How do I read css file relatively from my master page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io

In my ASP.NET project.  I put my css file in

```
\App_Themes\Default\theme.css
```

This is right under my project folder with all the aspx, master, web.config, etc.

How do I read that into a string using relative pathing from my .Master page?  In C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *.aspx page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <link runat="server" href="~/App_Themes\Default\theme.css" 
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

Or from the code behind:

```
string path = ResolveUrl("~/App_Themes\Default\theme.css");
// or 
string path = ResolveClientUrl("~/App_Themes\Default\theme.css");
```

(Description of the behavior and the difference between the twocan be found at: http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/ResolveUrl-vs-ResolveClientUrl.aspx)

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

This should return the full path to your css folder

```
Server.MapPath("App_Themes\Default\theme.css")
```

more info can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx